# Date().toLocaleString() output format is different on the live server and localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

in my nodejs app i need date in the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format , i use this simple code

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
```

in the local computer i get

`2019-1-8 04:14:28`  which is the correct format but the same code in the live server gives me `1/8/2019, 4:14:00 AM` which is not what i want .... why is that and how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

> The toLocaleString() method returns a string with a language sensitive
>   representation of this date. The new locales and options arguments let
>   applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should
>   be used and customize the behavior of the function. In older
>   implementations, which ignore the locales and options arguments, the
>   locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely
>   implementation dependent.

Example:

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// British English uses day-month-year order and 24-hour time without AM/PM
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
// expected output: 20/12/2012, 03:00:00

// Korean uses year-month-day order and 12-hour time with AM/PM
console.log(event.toLocaleString('ko-KR', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
// expected output: 2012. 12. 20. 오전 3:00:00
```

You are not passing the location parameter to `toLocaleString`, so the current location will be used. You see a different output on your machine vs. remote server because they are physically located in different countries.

Comment: but the time is the same , if it was the timezone issue shouldn't i be getting different time in the output ... date-time is the same only format changes (btw i've set the server timezone the same as my local machine  )

Comment: The issue is not the timezone, but the location - check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js for date and time manipulations.

```
moment("2010-10-20 4:30:12",  "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");   // parsed as 4:30:12 local time
moment("2010-10-20 4:30 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"); // parsed as 4:30 UTC
```

More info can be found at the [Moment String Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).